# how to revert the recyclerview items color after the ontouch method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want that after clicking the recycler view item reverts to its original color like it was before but if after i call the thread.sleep and after this change the textview color and imageview image to original it then doesn't shows the changed one  it shows the output after completely executing the touchlistener is there any function which would execute after the touchlistener

This is MyAdapter class

```
          private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;  // Declaring Variable to Understand which View is being worked on
                                       // IF the view under inflation and       population is header or Item
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

         private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles Value from MainActivity.java
 private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons       resource value from MainActivity.java
   // static TextView text; 
   // static ImageView image;
   private String name;        //String Resource for header View Name
    private int profile;        //int Resource for header view profile picture
   private String email;       //String Resource for header view email 
   static Context context;

           static int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.menu_inactivefind,R.drawable.menu_inactiveprofile,R.drawable.menu_inactiveapplied,R.drawable.menu_inactiveapplied,R.drawable.menu_inactiveresume,R.drawable.menu_inactivenews,R.drawable.menu_inactivesupport,R.drawable.menu_inactivesignout,R.drawable.menu_inactivesearch};
         static int ICONS2[] = {R.drawable.findactive,R.drawable.profileactive,R.drawable.appliedactive,R.drawable.appliedactive,R.drawable.resumeactive,R.drawable.newsactive,R.drawable.support1,R.drawable.signout,R.drawable.search};


   // Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
     // ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to recycle them

      public static class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder     implements View.OnClickListener{
     int Holderid;      

     static TextView textView; 
       static ImageView imageView;
     ImageView profile;
     TextView Name;
     TextView email;

       public ViewHolder1(View itemView,int ViewType,Context c) {                           // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
       super(itemView);
        context=c;

    // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created

        if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
         textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
         imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
         Holderid = 1;
        // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row

         // TextView im= ((ViewHolder) itemView.getTag()).textView;
           Log.i("view",String.valueOf(textView));

         }
         else{


              Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
             email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
              profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);// Creating Image view object from header.xml for profile pic
             Holderid = 0;                                                //    Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
         }
      }


     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub


       Toast.makeText(context,"The Item Clicked is:       "+getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


        Log.i("inside",String.valueOf(textView));
        }
        }


  MyAdapter(String Titles[],int Icons[],String Name,String Email, int    Profile)     { // MyAdapter Constructor with titles and icons parameter
                                    // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the main activity as we
      mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
      mIcons = Icons;
      name = Name;
      email = Email;
      profile = Profile;                     //here we assign those passed v alues to the values we declared here
//in adapter
     //  Log.i("myad cons",text.toString());
      }

    //Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when the ViewHolder is
  //Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
  // if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
   // and pass it to the view holder

       @Override
          public MyAdapter.ViewHolder1 onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

         if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
         View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

          ViewHolder1 vhItem = new ViewHolder1(v,viewType, context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

         return vhItem; // Returning the created object

    //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder

         } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

          View v =    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

           ViewHolder1 vhHeader = new ViewHolder1(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

          return vhHeader; //returning the object created


       }
       return null;

         }

   //Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is needed to be displayed, here the int position
  // Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed and the holder id of the holder object tell us
  // which view type is being created 1 for item row
       @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder1 holder, int position)         {
         if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is  going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
                                                      // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
           holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
           holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons

         }
          else{

     //    holder.profile.setImageResource(profile);           // Similarly we set the resources for header view
           holder.Name.setText(name);
           holder.email.setText(email);
           }


           }

       // This method returns the number of items present in the list
           @Override
           public int getItemCount() {
           return mNavTitles.length+1; // the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
          }


      // Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
         @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) { 
         if (isPositionHeader(position))
          return TYPE_HEADER;

           return TYPE_ITEM;
          }

       private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
       return position == 0;
       }
     }
```

this is the listener in the main activity

```
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new             RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {


            @Override
              public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());



            if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){
              //Drawer.closeDrawers();
             Toast.makeText(home.this,"The Item Clicked is: "+recyclerView.getChildPosition(child),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // ImageView imageView1 = imageView;
            //TextView textView1 = textView;

            im = ((ViewHolder1) recyclerView.getTag()).imageView;
            te = ((ViewHolder1) recyclerView.getTag()).textView;
               im.setImageResource(ICONS2[(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child))-1]);
           te.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
           Log.i("text",String.valueOf(te.toString()));

              return true;
           }
          return false;
          }
```

The attached image is when i click and after click it should be like other items
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my above mentioned issue by changing the click listener in the myadapter of recycler view a follows

```
    holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          holder.imageView.setImageResource(ICONS[position -1]);
         holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }         
        });
        Log.i("position",String.valueOf(position));

    }
```

and the touch listener in the main activity as follows.write the following code inside the onintercept touch event

```
       if(txt!=null)
           {

                img.setImageResource(ICONS2[(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child)-1)]);
           txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));}
```